# Disassembling x instruction from program memory

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi, disassembly

I'm working on simple debugger for Windows x86 platform, just for tests. I have implemented almost all functionality I need, except code disassembling. I decide that I use udis86 library but it is not important in my case.

In 0x86 - 0x64 architecture any instruction can has at most 15 bytes lenght, so
how I can get excatly 10 instructions started from e.g 0x4000bcda?

I have following code.

```
void disassembly(HANDLE hProcess, DWORD address) 
{
  BYTE buffer[15];   
  SIZE_T bytes_read;

 GetProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPBYTE) address, buffer, sizeof(buffer),   &bytes_read);
}
```

When the GetProcessMemory function doesn't failed, buffer should be filled with data.

But I can't assume that buffer contains fixed amount of instructuions. It may be one, two or whatever.

Maybe you have any ideas how it should be implemented?

Here is my current solution:

```
SIZE_T bytes_read;
BYTE buffer[4096];


if (!ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPBYTE)address, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytes_read)) {
    std::cout << "Cannot read process memory -> dissasembly." << std::endl;

    return;
}
printf("Address : %#010x\n", address);
std::cout << "Disassembled code: " << std::endl;
ud_t ud_obj;

ud_init(&ud_obj);
ud_set_input_buffer(&ud_obj, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
ud_set_mode(&ud_obj, 64);
ud_set_syntax(&ud_obj, UD_SYN_INTEL);

int counter = 0;
int instructionAmount = 10;

while (ud_disassemble(&ud_obj)) {
    printf("\t%s\n", ud_insn_asm(&ud_obj));

    counter++;

    if (counter == instructionAmount) {
        break;
    }
}
```

It basically works but in m opinion it does not good solution and it may cause errors

Comment: Could you be more specific about your concerns and the errors your current solution may cause?

Comment: What if the buffer size will be not enought?

Comment: "*how I can get excatly 10 instructions started from e.g 0x4000bcda?*" - by starting at the address and decoding instructions one at a time until you have decoded 10 instructions.  Instructions are variable length, so you have to decode them in sequence.

Comment: One instruction is at most 15 bytes, 10 instructions are at most 150 bytes. Seems straightforward to me.

Comment: Let's face it, 15 byte instructions are a pathological case.  I believe it is to stop the CPU from trying to decode an infinitely long sequence of prefixes (an unfortunate fill pattern, maybe).

Comment: _What if the buffer size will be not enough?_  Then `GetProcessMemory` some more!

Answer (score 0):

You said the max bytes per instruction is 15 and you want to read 10 instructions, so 15 x 10 = 150.  That is how much memory you should read in your call to ReadProcessMemory.

But the instructions won't consume that much memory, once you read that memory into your local buffer, you will have to read each instruction starting at buffer[0], decode it, get it's length, index into the next instruction, decode the instruction and continue until the number of instructions decoded is reached 10.  The combined length of all the instructions you decoded represents the last byte in the buffer of your 10 instructions.

You will have to increase the instruction counter and a seperate number of bytes counter one each iteration.